# Getting messed with wrong array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I saved an array `sequence` to `reset`. I deleted each element from `sequence`, performing an operation, then reset `sequence` to its former state.

```
reset = sequence
(0..sequence.length).each do |i|
  puts "Sequence #{sequence}, index is #{i}.  Deleting #{sequence[i]}"
  sequence.delete_at(i)
  puts "New sequence is #{sequence.inspect}, sorted makes #{sequence.sort}, unique makes #{sequence.uniq}"
  return true if sequence.sort == sequence && sequence.uniq == sequence
  puts "This is reset before the sequence = reset: #{reset.inspect}"
  sequence = reset
  puts "Resetting sequence. Reset is #{reset.inspect}, sequence is #{sequence.inspect}"
  dummy = gets.chomp
end
```

Then, what happened to `sequence` also happened to `reset`. Here is some output:

```
Sequence [1, 1, 1, 2, 3], index is 0.  Deleting 1
New sequence is [1, 1, 2, 3], sorted makes [1, 1, 2, 3], unique makes [1, 2, 3]
This is reset before the sequence = reset: [1, 1, 2, 3]
Resetting sequence. Reset is [1, 1, 2, 3], sequence is [1, 1, 2, 3]
```

It's mucking about `reset` when I only commanded it to delete from `sequence`. It's not the case that `reset = sequence` is inside the loop. What gives? The loop was supposed to break at `oldarray.size`, inside which it was pushing elements into a new array. But inexplicably, it pushed the same numbers into the same array as well, thereby creating an infinite loop.

Comment: `reset = sequence`. Of course, whatever you do to `sequence` is done to `reset`.

Answer (score 3):

`reset` and `sequence` are *the same array*. The `=` operator doesn't copy the contents of an array or other object; it creates a new reference to the same array.

For example, try this in `irb`:

```
irb(main):001:0> a = [ 10, 20 ]
=> [10, 20]
irb(main):002:0> b = a
=> [10, 20]
irb(main):003:0> a
=> [10, 20]
irb(main):004:0> b
=> [10, 20]
irb(main):005:0> a.push( 30 )
=> [10, 20, 30]
irb(main):006:0> b.push( 40 )
=> [10, 20, 30, 40]
irb(main):007:0> a
=> [10, 20, 30, 40]
irb(main):008:0> b
=> [10, 20, 30, 40]
```

The same is true when you pass an array or any object in a method call. The method doesn't get a separate copy of the object data; it receives a reference to the same object:

```
irb(main):001:0> a = [ 10, 20 ]
=> [10, 20]
irb(main):002:0> def foo( x );  x.push( 30 );  end
=> :foo
irb(main):003:0> foo( a )
=> [10, 20, 30]
irb(main):004:0> a
=> [10, 20, 30]
```

Note that `foo` didn't just modify its `x` parameter, it also modified the `a` that was passed into it, because `x` and `a` are both references to the same array.

If you want to make a copy of an array so that operations on it are independent of the original, you can use `dup` or `clone`:

```
irb(main):001:0> a = [ 10, 20 ]
=> [10, 20]
irb(main):002:0> b = a.clone
=> [10, 20]
irb(main):003:0> a
=> [10, 20]
irb(main):004:0> b
=> [10, 20]
irb(main):005:0> a.push( 30 )
=> [10, 20, 30]
irb(main):006:0> b.push( 40 )
=> [10, 20, 40]
irb(main):007:0> a
=> [10, 20, 30]
irb(main):008:0> b
=> [10, 20, 40]
```

Many languages work like this; the assignment operator or a function parameter doesn't copy any data but merely creates a new reference to the same data.

Here's the same example in Python:

```
>>> a = [ 10, 20 ]
>>> b = a
>>> a
[10, 20]
>>> b
[10, 20]
>>> a.append( 30 )
>>> b.append( 40 )
>>> a
[10, 20, 30, 40]
>>> b
[10, 20, 30, 40]
```

and in JavaScript:

```
a = [ 10, 20 ]
  (2) [10, 20]
b = a
  (2) [10, 20]
a.push( 30 )  // .push() returns the array length
  3
b.push( 40 )
  4
a
  (4) [10, 20, 30, 40]
b
  (4) [10, 20, 30, 40]
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we write

```
sequence = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
reset = sequence
  #=> [1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```

The variables `sequence` and `reset` do not only hold the same value, they hold the same object:

```
sequence.object_id
  #=> 4044000
reset.object_id
  #=> 4044000
```

Note that variables do not have object id's; it is their values--Ruby objects-- that have unique ids (see [Object#object_id](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-object_id)). When we write `sequence.object_id`, `sequence` returns `[1, 1, 1, 2, 3]` and then `[1, 1, 1, 2, 3].object_id #=> 4044000` is returned.

If the object `[1, 1, 1, 2, 3]` is changed the values of the two variables will both equal the changed object.

```
sequence.replace [1, 4]
  #=> [1, 4]
sequence.object_id
  #=> 4044000
reset
  #=> [1, 4]
reset.object_id
  #=> 4044000
```

On the other hand, if we set either of these variables to equal a difference object (which will have a different object id), the value of the other variable is unaffected.

```
sequence = [99, 31]
sequence.object_id
  #=> 5564720
reset
  #=> [1, 4]
reset.object_id
  #=> 4044000
```

Comment: That information...is nowhere to be found in the study material I was provided.

So is there a non-brute force way to reset an especially large array after deleting one element?

Comment: If you wish to do that you would normally use a method that creates a new array without *mutating* (changing) the original array. For example, `arr1 = [1,2,3]; arr2 = arr1.reject { |e| e == 2 } #=> [1,3]` leaves `arr1` unchanged (`[1,2,3]`). See [Array#reject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-reject). If you delete elements from `arr1` (mutating that array) and later want to change `arr1` back to the way it was you'd have to keep track of the values and their indices that were deleted from `arr1`, which is doable but messy. Does that answer your question?

Comment: You said my answer was not contained in your study material, but does it make sense? Does it answer your question?